# Invalid rowid error

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursors, locking

I'm trying to see, how UPDATE Lock helps to minimize error while dml (delete/update) operations.

```
declare
 cursor update_lock is select empno from emp where deptno=&no for update of sal;
 num number;
begin
 --for i in update_lock loop
 --end loop;
 open update_lock;
 loop
   fetch update_lock into num;
   exit when update_lock%notfound;
   dbms_output.put_line(num);
 end loop;
 update emp set sal=sal+10 where current of update_lock;
 close update_lock;
end;
```

I'm using very simple code to check, how does it works. But, it showing **Invalid ROWID**. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: i'm just checking the output of the cursor.

Comment: @jWeavers: please remember to always include a tag for the database system you're using (unless it's a database-agnostic question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is going through all the rows in `emp` for `deptno=&no`, without updating them. When you reach the end of the result set (one past the last row), `exit when udpate_lock%notfound` triggers and you jump out of the loop, to the `update` statement.

At that point, the cursor is invalid. You've gone beyond the last row. So the `update [...] where current of` will fail - there is no `current of` for `update_lock`, the cursor isn't positioned on a row.